# Python argparse mutual exclusive args

Tags: python, argparse

How can I make argparse do something like:

```
[ 'all' | [ pos1 [ pos2 [ pos3 ...]]]] --some --other --flags
```

where `all` is a reserved word *(making it a flag would not be ok if it doesn't need a `-` prefix)*

Second:
is it possible to have some aliases for named parameters like `-h` and `--help` meaning the same option? Maybe I should try with `add_mutually_exclusive_group()`?

Answer (score 4):

add_mutually_exclusive_group() is designed for exactly this - you are trying to add a mutually exclusive group.

In regards to the second part of your question, this should do what you want:

```
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foobar')
```

(Note: your question is a bit confusing - there are two questions there and the second question runs straight into another sentence about the first question. Not to mention the numerous typos... I'll try and help but the clearer you can make the question the clearer we can answer you.)

**Update**
As far as I can tell mutually exclusive arguments *must* be required but positional arguments *cannot* be required. Therefore positional arguments cannot be mutually exclusive (presumably because otherwise the interpreter wouldn't be able to tell what was what). For your purposes I don't think this really matters as the code that interprets your arguments would be practically the same either way.

Assuming you *could* do it the way you are trying to then have to do something like this:

```
# all == True  
# pos == ('this', 'that', 'theother')

if all == true:
    do_some_stuff('all')
else:
    do_some_other_stuff('positional arguments')
```

Whereas if you accept "all" as one of your positional arguments you would have to do this:

```
# pos = ('all', 'this, 'that', 'theother')

if pos[0] == 'all': #other parameters are ignored
    do_some_stuff('all')
else:
    do_some_other_stuff('positional arguments')
```

Unless you have some specific reason, I see no reason not to do it the latter way.

Comment: so 'all' should be a flag param and 'pos' a positional param and both should go into a mutual exclusive group? 

sorry, but this doesn't do the trick

Positional and Flags don't seem to be going into the same group.
i also keep getting a "ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional"

Comment: Logically mutually exclusive arguments have to be optional. If one of them was mandatory then they would no longer be mutually exclusive. Are you sure that both of yours are set as optional? Sorry if that sounds obvious!

Comment: hm.. maybe i could not explain the problem right. Lets get a step back.
I'd like to accept  0 .. n positional parameters.
If the first "positional" parameter is the reseverd word 'all' i'd like to accept no furhter positional parameters. In any case i accept flags or named parameters. I found no way to do that in argparse. Of course i can do it by examining the contents of the positional paramerts list later on.

Comment: the second sample is what i have actually implemented. It would have been a "nice to have", if i could reject the extra positionals in the 'all' case while parsing the arguments.
there is the code:
   parser.add_argument('modules', metavar='MOD',  nargs='*',  help="list of modules or 'all'")
   parser.add_argument('-s','--recursive', dest='recursive',action='store_true', help='rekursiv') 
...
...
   if len(args.modules) == 0:
       ...
    elif len(args.modules) == 1 and args.modules[0].lower() == 'all':
       ...
    else:
      for d in args.modules:         
        ...

Comment: Ah...you mean actually raise an error as opposed to silently ignoring them? It should be possible to make argparse raise an error, though you'd probably have to implement it yourself somehow... You've piqued my interest! I've just finished work but I'll try and help more this evening/tomorrow.

Comment: deriving from argparse.ArgumentParser? I don't think folks intentended to do so. i'd rather stick to the official API because any other solution is possibly unstable with the next release. Maybe multi-stage parsing with ArgumentParser.parse_known_args could provide an answer? also subcommands looks interesting where 'all' could be the subcommand.